# Rendering view for an element in rails by :id

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, routes, erb

I have a sidebar that contains links to all of a users :shopping_lists. Upon clicking on one of those links, I'd like to render a page showing the `:list_items` in that particular list. Here's my sidebar partial:

```
<aside class="sidebar-nav-fixed">

    <h1>My Lists</h1>

    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <% current_user.shopping_lists.each do |l| %>
            <ul>
                <%= link_to "#{l.name}", '#' %>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <h5><%= link_to "Sign in to manage lists.", new_user_session_path %></h5>
    <% end %>
</aside>
```

My question is: what path would I be putting in place of my current stub link in order to route to the correct list? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things you can do, granted your routes are setup correctly:

The easiest is:

```
link_to "#{l.name}", l
```

Rails should create a link something similar to `http://host/shopping_lists/2`

The above is a shorthand for

```
link_to "#{l.name}", shopping_list_path(l)
```

To see a list of available routes and methods you can run:

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

in the root of your rails app

Comment: Worked perfectly after I sorted out my bad controller-naming habits. As a follow up, once I land on that view, how can I reference the :id of this list in that view? For instance, if I wanted to display all list items within that list with `:id` '2' (as in the example you gave). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for a delay. That actually has to do with how your models are setup. Technically you could just iterate over all items in the list in your view (using eager loading of course). If you could update your question with a sample of how you model Shopping List and migration is setup I could give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

That will depend on how your routes are setup. I would expect shopping lists to always be in the context of a user, so probably something like this:

```
<%= link_to l.name, user_shopping_list_path(current_user, l) %>
```

If shopping lists are a top level route, then probably something like this:

```
<%= link_to l.name, shopping_list_path(l) %>
```